Global uniqueness of the solution to a specific nonlinear ODE system with "global" initial condition
I get stuck trying to prove the uniqueness of the solution $y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$ to the following system of nonlinear ODE's
\begin{align*}
y'_1&=\frac{y_1-y_2}{\xi(t)-y_1}\xi'(t)\\
y'_2&=\frac{y_2-h(t)}{\xi(t)-y_1}\xi'(t)
\end{align*}
satysfying the "global" initial condition
$$
h(t)<y_2<y_1<\xi(t),\quad t\in(\alpha,\beta).
$$
Here, $h$ and $\xi$ are two strictly increasing functions defined on $(\alpha,\beta)\subset\mathbb R$, $h$ is continuous, $\xi$ is differentiable, and such that
$$
h(t)<\xi(t)\quad\text{for all $t\in(\alpha,\beta)$, but}\quad \xi(\beta)=h(\beta).
$$
Of course, $h(\beta)$ is understood as the limit of $h$ at $\beta$, as well as $\xi(\beta)$.
If we fix $t_0\in(\alpha,\beta)$ and $y^0=\begin{pmatrix}y_1^0\\y_2^0\end{pmatrix}$ such that $h(t_0)<y_2^0<y_1^0<\xi(t_0)$, then the right hand side of the system is Lipschitz with respect to $y$. Therefore the system has locally unique solution such that $y(t_0)=y^0$. An application of Ważewski retract principle guarantees the existence of at least one solution $\varphi=\begin{pmatrix}\varphi_1\\ \varphi_2\end{pmatrix}$ satisfying the global condition $h(t)<\varphi_2<\varphi_1<\xi(t)$ on the whole interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. My claim is that for the above system this solution is unique.
Under the same assumptions on $h$ and $\xi$, I have managed to prove this claim for the case of a single ODE
$$
y'=\frac{y-h(t)}{\xi(t)-y}\xi'(t)
$$
satisfying $h(t)<y<\xi(t)$. Indeed, let $\varphi$ denote any solution which existence follows again by Ważewski principle. If $y$ is any other solutions to the problem, then by the local uniqueness of solutions, $y$ and $\varphi$ cannot intersect. So, either $y>\varphi$ or $y<\varphi$ on $(\alpha,\beta)$. Simple calculations show that
$$
(y-\varphi)'=\frac{(y-\varphi)(\xi-h)}{(\xi-y)(\xi-\varphi)}\xi'. 
$$
By our assumptions, we have $\xi-h>0$ and $\xi'>0$. Also, $h<y<\xi$ and $h<\varphi<\xi$ imply that the denominator is positive. Therefore, the sign of $(y-\varphi)'$ is the same as that of $y-\varphi$. This means that if $\varphi<y<\xi$, then the difference $y-\varphi$ is strictly increasing from positive value, so it cannot converge to 0 at $t=\beta$. On the other hand, since $h<\varphi<y<\xi$, then
$$
0\leq y-\varphi<\xi-h\to 0,
$$
as $t\to\beta$. This is a contradiction. The other case when $y<\varphi$ goes the same way. This shows the global uniqueness of the solution to ODE $y'=\frac{y-h}{\xi-y}\xi'$ such that $h<y<\xi$ on $(\alpha,\beta)$.
Now back to the original system. If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^2$, then for two solutions $y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\varphi=\begin{pmatrix}\varphi_1\\ \varphi_2\end{pmatrix}$ we again have $\|y-\varphi\|\to 0$ as $t\to\beta$.
My first approach to prove the uniqueness was to mimick the above arguments. It would be sufficient if we prove that $\|y-\varphi\|$ is strictly increasing. To this aim let's compute the derivative of $\|y-\varphi\|^2$. We have
$$
\frac d{dt}\|y-\varphi\|^2=2\langle y'-\varphi',y-\varphi\rangle.
$$
Next, after some computations we obtain
\begin{align*}
(y_1-\varphi_1)'&=\frac {\xi'}{(\xi-y)(\xi-\varphi)}[(\xi-y_2)(y_1-\varphi_1)-(\xi-y_1)(y_2-\varphi_2)]\\
(y_2-\varphi_2)'&=\frac {\xi'}{(\xi-y)(\xi-\varphi)}[(y_2-h)(y_1-\varphi_1)+(\xi-y_1)(y_2-\varphi_2)]
\end{align*}
It can be written in the matrix form
$$
(y-\varphi)'=\frac {\xi'}{(\xi-y)(\xi-\varphi)}
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi-y_2 & -(\xi-y_1)\\
y_2-h   & \xi-y_1
\end{pmatrix}
(y-\varphi)
$$
However, I am not able to use this expressions to show that $\frac d{dt}\|y-\varphi\|^2\geq 0$.
My second approach was to consider auxiliary functions $z=y_1+y_2$ and $\eta=\varphi_2+\varphi_2$. Obviously both the functions are increasing and their difference also goes to 0 as $t\to\beta$. The idea is to find the contradiction by proving that $z-\varphi$ is increasing. It is easy to compute that
$$
(z-\eta)'=\frac{(y_1-\varphi_1)(\xi-h)}{(\xi-y_1)(\xi-\varphi_1)}\xi'.
$$
So as above the sign of the derivative $(z-\eta)'$ is the same as that of the difference $y_1-\varphi_1$. Notice that in this case the local uniqueness implies that for any $t\in(\alpha,\beta)$ we have $y_1(t)\neq\varphi_1(t)$ or $y_2(t)\neq\varphi_2(t)$. So we cannot conclude right away that $y_1>\varphi_1$ or $y_1<\varphi_1$, as we did for the single ODE. Therefore, we cannot infer that $(z-\eta)'>0$.
My impression is that if $y_1(t_0)=\varphi_1(t_0)$ for some $t_0\in(\alpha,\beta)$, then this implies $y_2(t_0)=\varphi_2(t_0)$ as well. (This would contradict the local uniqueness of the solution of the system). I have tried to prove this claim applying the above expression for $(y-\varphi)'$ from the first approach, but with no luck.
If you have gone this far, you have probably realized that it is only a special two-dimensional case of a general system
\begin{align*}
y'_1&=\frac{y_1-y_2}{\xi(t)-y_1}\xi'(t)\\
y'_2&=\frac{y_2-y_3}{\xi(t)-y_1}\xi'(t)\\
&\vdots\\
y'_k&=\frac{y_k-h(t)}{\xi(t)-y_1}\xi'(t).
\end{align*}
The problem is to prove that there exists exactly one solution $y=(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)^T$ such that $h<y_k<\dotsc<y_2<y_1<\xi$. The problem is interesting on its own, but its solution would be very useful to prove the uniqueness of the characterization of probability distributions by the regressions of order statistics. Let me know in the comments if you want to know more details.
Do you guys have any idea how to prove the uniqueness? Or maybe I am missing something obvious? Maybe any suggestions of a different approach?
Best regards,
Mariusz
